# Phonegap does not load json - browser does

Tags: jquery, ios, json, cordova

I made a Phonegap/cordova 2.3 app that loads a recipe list in json from the server and outputs the names of the recipes. In the browser it is working fine. But when I compile to iOS the json is not loaded, I see a blank screen. However when I put the server-output in a file in the public folder and load that file, it does work in iOS. So I would say there is nothing wrong with the json-output.

```
function load() {
  $.getJSON('http://localhost:3000/nl/recipes.json', function(data) {
  for (i in data) {
    document.write(data[i].name+"<br>")
  }           
});
```

External hosts are allowed in the config-file:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What is your server? Accessing `localhost` from the phone could be the problem

Comment: Is your phone the webserver?

Comment: The phone is not the webserver, but I use the iPhone simulator. The webserver is on the same machine as the simulator. Please note that the iPhone simulator does load localhost:3000/test.json

Answer (score 4):

The address is not *localhost* anymore since you are on a different machine.

If you are on the same network, you need to change `localhost` to your computer's local ip address. Something like this;

```
$.getJSON('http://192.168.1.10:3000/nl/recipes.json', function(data) {
 ...
});
```

Comment: I tried that. It didn't help unfortunately. If that would be the solution, how could it be that iOS does load the file in the public folder (with same contents)? I used this location: http://localhost:3000/test.json and it worked.

Comment: Fixed it. The problem was not the localhost, but required authorization.